# Vlook up unable to get the property of the worksheetfunction class vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a list that my code format is a combination of text and number. for example WO-01779809.
I want to search just number part of this code by using a Textbox and extract address and customer information based on thies code and place a quote, but error 1004 unable to get the property of the worksheetfunction class vlookup happens. I tried to change the formats of cells or my text box and make it same (text or number) but any change.

For number Format

```
    Columns("d:d").NumberFormat = "0"
    TextBox1.Value = CLng(TextBox1.Value)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").Range("x3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TextBox1.Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO").Range("WOlist"), 26, True)
```

For text Format

```
    Columns("d:d").NumberFormat = "@"
    TextBox1.Value = StrConv(TextBox1.Value, vbProperCase)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote").Range("x3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TextBox1.Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO").Range("WOlist"), 26, True)
```

I dont Know what els most I do ?
Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelp

Comment: Where does your code occur (what module, procedure or event)?

Comment: I tried reproducing your error but couldn't. The target cell was populated as expected.

Comment: when the person write the workorder number in the text box and klick the done botton